# Installing Gazebo Simulator on Windows 10: Missing: Ignition math3 library

Tags: installation, ros

I want to use ROS and Gazebo for some robotics simulations, so I am trying to install Gazebo on my Windows 10 machine, following this guide: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows

I have gotten to step 10 at the line `..\configure`, at which point I get the error:

```
-- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
--      Missing: Ignition math3 library.
-- END BUILD ERRORS
```

In step 9 I could see that `ignition-math4` was installed.

**How do I install `Ignition math3`?**

Answer (score 1):

From gazebo answers: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16234/how-to-install-ignition-math3-on-windows-10/?answer=16253#post-id-16253

> The instructions are building the default branch of ign-math, which
>   currently corresponds to version 4.
>
> For version 3, add the hg up ign-math3 command to step 9, as follows:
>
> ```
> cd ign-math
> hg up ign-math3
> mkdir build
> cd build
> # if you want debug, run ..\configure Debug
> ..\configure Release
> nmake
> nmake install
> ```